# Why do I get compile error? using try and catch

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int x = 0, y = 10;
        try {
            y /=x;
        }
        System.out.print(" / by 0");
        catch(exception e) {
            System.out.print("error");
        }
}
```

Using try and catch, I have built code above and the output is compile error. The output I expected was "error" since a number divided by zero gives an ArithmeticException. Why do I get compile error above?

Comment: Spelling error for exception -> Exception, also move the catch block next to try block

Comment: When you write a question about an compile-time error, *always* specify the error in the question.

Comment: pls format your code (completely ;-)) thx

Answer (score 2):

You can't seperate the `try` from the `catch` block. This got you the compilation error.
Correct code would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 0, y = 10;
    try {
        y /= x;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print(" / by 0");
        System.out.print("error");
    }
}
```

Also, you had `Exception` lowercase, which would have caused another problem.

Answer (score 0):

A catch block is supposed to be immediately followed by try block. Put the print line statement inside catch block. Also, Exception is a class of Java, exception is not.

So, put the catch keyword immediately after the try block (}) ends, or in the next line.